Sort an array of duplicated items by placing the first occurrences first
I have an array of items that occur exactly twice, right next to eachother, like so:
const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']

I need to sort it in a different order, so all unique values occur first, and then their duplicates, like so:
const arr = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']

How can I solve it by using sort() function? Or is there another way I can achieve this?
I tried something like this, but it didn't work:
const sorted = myDublicatedArray.sort((left, right) => left.index - right.index);


To be clear, are you interested in the numeric values in any fashion, or is it more a case of changing the items in positions abcdef to acebdf? "How can I solve it by using sort() function?" Is using sort() a hard requirement?

You need it do be done with sort? Is that the question? What if there are fewer of one value than another? How should it be distributed then? Can you gave more examples, and non-trivial ones?

I am more interested in position of items, not the numeric values. It's not required to use sort(). What do you have in mind otherwise if not using sort?

@tech27 Are the input values always immediately after one another? (e.g. [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] or is the input more random?

What is the expected output for [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]?

@HunterMcMillen values are immediately one after another

@trincot it's not the case, the values always will be one after another and always in dublicate

Not sure I understand what "one after another" means. I thought I had presented an array with one value after another.

Do I understand correctly that your input will have every value occurring exactly twice, and always next to eachother?

@trincot I think Hunter McMillen answer solved my problem

Yes, but I still want to understand the question exactly, so we can suggest updates to the question and also have some other answers posted, so you can compare. Can you confirm my last comment?

Alright, as you wrote before yes every value occurring exactly twice, and always next to each other.

Great. In the mean time there are 3 answers and I guess some more can follow.

I updated your question to integrate the results of the clarifying comments. Hope it matches what you intend.

I can't think of a way to do this only using Array.sort(). The approach below should work for both numeric and string inputs unless there are other requirements:


const arrayWithDuplicates = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'];
// convert to a Set to get unique values
const uniqueValues = new Set(arrayWithDuplicates);
// sort by value
const sortedArray = Array.from(uniqueValues).sort((a, b) => a - b);
// duplicate the sorted array
const arrayOrganized = [...sortedArray].concat(sortedArray);

console.log(arrayOrganized)




From comments I understand that you will have pairs of duplicate values following one after the other, never 3 or more of the same. In that case, you can map the input array like this:


const arrayWithDuplicates = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'];
const result = arrayWithDuplicates.map((_, i, a) => a[i * 2 % a.length]);
console.log(result);



And if speed is a requirement, then go for an old-fashioned for loop:


const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'];
const result = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
        result.push(arr[i]);
console.log(result);




What the meaning of _ in map()? Does it mean you skip item?

_ is a variable name (identifiers can start with underscore) for the first parameter (which is the array element), but gives the reader the hint that this parameter is not used. I added another version that just uses old-fashioned for loops.

You could maintain an index for every value and get a grouped array as first and then a flat array as result.


const
    array = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
    result = array
        .reduce((indices => (r, v) => {
            indices[v] ??= 0;
            (r[indices[v]++] ??= []).push(v);
            return r;
        })({}), [])
        .flat();

console.log(result);




You can use sort for this. First, map the elements to [element, occurrence] pairs. For example, the first occurrence of 2 is mapped to [2,0].
Then, sort first by occurrence, and for elements with equal occurrence, sort by the element itself.
Finally, extract just the element from the [element, occurrence] pair.


const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']

const result = Object.values(Object.groupBy(arr, e => e))
  .flatMap(arr => arr.map((e,i) => [e,i]))
  .sort(([a,i], [b,j]) => i-j || a-b)
  .map(([e]) => e)

console.log(result)




If the values are already sorted and values are always present in sets of 2 you could use the following:


const arr = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'];
const uniq = new Set(arr);
const desired = Array.from({ length: 2 }).flatMap(() => Array.from(uniq));

console.log(desired);



The snippet above creates a Set uniq that contains all unique values in the array. To get the desired result we create an array with length 2 with Array.from(), then use flatMap() to fill and expand the array. We can use Array.from() to convert uniq from a Set to an array. The item order is based on insertion order ('1', then '2', then '3').
If the amount of duplicates can be dynamic (but is the same across the whole array) you could make it more dynamic by using Array.from({ length: arr.length / uniq.size }). This would allow the following inputs:
const arr = ['1', '2', '3'];
const arr = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'];

Note that the elements are still expected to be sorted and to be consistent in duplicate amount.
